# Reconstruct unsaved QuickOSM layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, quickosm

Having made some maps by querying OpenStreetMap last evening I went to bed after having saved my work. QGIS prompted me that there were some in-memory layers that would not be saved, but provided me with no further information on how to go about saving that data. Being tired I was unable to figure out what the prompt meant and closed the application after saving.

Waking up I find that all may layers are gone. Is there any way I can go about reconstructing them?

Answer (score 3):

By rightclicking the layer -> Properties -> Variables you can find the query used to create the layer under Layer -> quickosm_query. Copy the text and paste it into QuickOSM -> Query and then pressing Run query. That way you will get a new layer based on the same query.